# Django object multiple exclude()

Tags: django, django-queryset

Is there a way to do a query and exclude a list of things, instead of calling exclude multiple times?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Based on your reply to Ned, it sounds like you just want to exclude a list of tags. So you could just use the `in` filter:

```
names_to_exclude = [o.name for o in objects_to_exclude] 
Foo.objects.exclude(name__in=names_to_exclude)
```

Does that do what you want?

Comment: I do it with a list of objects_to_exclude directly, I don't use the o.name:

ignore_tags = request.user.ignore_tags.all()
case_list = Case.objects.exclude(tags__in = ignore_tags))

Answer (score 11):

What's wrong with calling exclude multiple times?  Queries are lazy, nothing happens until you try to pull data from it, so there's no downside to using .exclude() more than once.

Comment: I have a model that has a tags manytomany field. the user can have a large amount of ignore tags.  I want to dynamically exclude the objects that the user doesn't want to see.  I won't know how many times to call exclude till run time.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "queries are lazy" and "pull data from it" ? Thnx

Comment: What lazy means is that no data will be pulled from the database untill the query is actually used.

Answer (score 8):

You can try this also.

`exclude_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
 qs = Foo.objects.exclude(items__in=exclude_list)`

Answer (score 5):

You can do it pretty easily with the [Q object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q

excludes = None
for tag in ignored_tags:
    q = Q(tag=tag)
    excludes = (excludes and (excludes | q)) or q # makes sure excludes is set properly
set_minus_excluded = Foo.objects.exclude(excludes)
```

You should also be able to do it dynamically with exclude():

```
qs = Foo.objects.all()
for tag in ignored_tags:
    qs = qs.exclude(tag=tag)
```

Answer (score 4):

To improve on Daniel Roseman's answer I think it would be better to get the values you need directly from the queryset instead of the for loop that could be expensive on large data sets i.e.

```
names_to_exclude = objects_to_exclude.values_list('name')
Foo.objects.exclude(name__in=names_to_exclude)
```