# Django, using ANY in a query

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-queryset

Basically i have to do this:

```
WHERE NOT (`video_video`.`id` = **ANY** (SELECT `userPreferences_history`.`video_id` FROM `userPreferences_history`))
```

but using:

```
.exclude(id=history_list)
```

i just get:

```
WHERE NOT (`video_video`.`id` = (SELECT `userPreferences_history`.`video_id` FROM `userPreferences_history`))
```

resulting in a **'Subquery returns more than 1 row** when i have more than 1 result from the subquery.

How can i do this?

**Fixed** following this way: [Django object multiple exclude()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912540/django-object-multiple-exclude)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `history_list` is the proper subquery, `.exclude(id__in=history_list)`.

Comment: As a general rule, if you are looking to get results out of a subquery, even if there is only one possible result, it is always better to use "in" than "=".